# Cannot display a 32 bit grayscale tif image in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, 32-bit

I am trying to open a 32-bit gray scale image from Photonic detector and Pilatus detector systems in tkinter. The displayed image in tkinter canvas is black. I couldn't find any working suggestion on this. I appreciate any help with the following code.
Thanks
[Pilatus image][1]

```
from skimage import io, img_as_float,  util, morphology
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas, Frame, Label, filedialog
img_data= img_as_float(io.imread("slice0040.tif"))
Width, Height=img_data.shape

#convert img_data to 8 bit using skimage
#and making an image for display using tkinter
img=Image.fromarray(util.img_as_ubyte(img_data))


root=Tk()


frame=LabelFrame(root,text='Image frame',width=Width,height=Height)
frame.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=2)

canvas = Canvas(frame, width=Width, height=Height)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=W)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((Width, Height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
img_container = canvas.create_image(Width-int(Width/2), int(Height)-int(Height/2), image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

This one works for both int type and float type images.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
# Load with PIL
im = Image.open('Pilatus.tif')
# Make into Numpy array and normalise
na   = np.array(im)
if im.mode =='F' :
    norm = cv2.normalize(na, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
else:
    norm = na
img=(norm*255).astype(np.uint8)

root=Tk()
Width=1000
Height=1000

label=Label(root,text="Root label",font=("Verdana",12))
label.grid(row=0,column=0)

frame=LabelFrame(root,text='Image frame',width=Width,height=Height)
frame.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=2)

print(Width,Height)
label=Label(frame,text="Image frame")
label.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)

canvas = Canvas(frame, width=Width, height=Height)
canvas.grid(row=3, column=0,sticky=W)
img=Image.fromarray(img)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((Width, Height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
img_container = canvas.create_image(Width-int(Width/2), int(Height)-int(Height/2), image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If it is a TIFF image, why don't you just use `PIL.Image` to load the image?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific libraries you're using, but generally an image in float format has pixel values in the range 0.0 thru 1.0.  If you blindly convert that to 8-bit integers, you only get pixel values that are 0 or 1 - in other words, "black" and "so close to black you can't tell the difference".

Comment: @acw1668, It is a 32 bit input image and PIL do not support 32 images to load. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: Based on the document on image [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes), PIL supports 32-bit image.  You can simply try to load the image using PIL and see whether it works or not.

Comment: @acw1668, Sorry I wasn't clear before. We can load the 32 bit image using PIL, but tkinter do not support 32 bit images. They need to be converted to 8 or 16 bit type before displaying them on canvas. I want to use image processing using skimage and that is why I am loading images using skimage.

Comment: If PIL can load the image, what is the error when you tried to use it in tkinter?  Also `PIL.Image` module has function to convert the color depth of the image.

Comment: I do not have much experience using PIL functions. I will try and let know. Thanks.

Comment: Try getting and printing the range of the values in the image with `getextrema()` https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getextrema

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the getextrema() for Pilatus image returns: (-2, 1577)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what constraints you have or exactly how critical absolute display accuracy is to you, but if you just want to get something visible on screen for now, you can normalise your data to the range 0..255 and call it `unsigned int 8` or `ubyte`.

So if it is currently in range -2..1577 you want to add 2 then it will be in range 0..1579. Then multiply by 255.0/1577.0, round it and call it `ubyte`. It should show up with a full contrast range.

Or with OpenCV

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load with PIL
im = Image.open('Photonics.tif')

# Make into Numpy array and normalise
na   = np.array(im)
norm = cv2.normalize(na, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

# Save
cv2.imwrite('Photonics-OpenCV.jpg', (norm*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell. I rescaled the intensities using scikit's rescale_intensity option. Now, I can see the original image but it is displaying only quarter of the image. Checked the dimensions and they are correct. Would you please suggest from this code where the problem is?

Comment: `#skimage
img_data= img_as_uint(io.imread("Pilatus.tif"))
img_data_contrast=exposure.rescale_intensity(img_data)
print(f'Max  and Min is  ', np.max(img_data_contrast),np.min(img_data_contrast))

img_data=img_data_contrast


Width, Height = img_data.shape

#convert img_data to 8 bit using skimage
#and making an image for display using PIL

img=Image.fromarray(img_data,mode='L')`

Comment: Please share your actual TIFF - using Google Drive or Dropbox or somesuch. Currently it is a PNG. Thank you.

Comment: the link to the images is here. the image Pilatus.tif is an int image and Photonics.tif is a float image. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qeECficCRsQHsAAnhk-0yU_JxrrvFzux?usp=sharing) Thank you

Comment: I am now confused by your question. Please clarify each of the following points, by number. 1) Which image do you have a problem with - Pilatus? Photonics? Both? 2) What is the actual problem? Is the image the wrong size/shape? Is the brightness wrong? 3) What is the image supposed to look like? Thank you.

Comment: Using sci-kit or cv2 functions, I can display the images correctly. 1) But the problem is when I want to use tkinter to display image in canvas or label, I only see black image. As you suggested, I rescaled intensities (realising they are of low contrast), then two problems arise, one is I could see the Pilatus image on the canvas but only 1/3rd of the image and the second is I still see a dark image for Photonics image.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, I updated code in the edited post and the Pilatus output is in this link [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TnmytnQDJh-2xxcd1zTondhAHLU2PwGh/view?usp=sharing)